# Laravel + Vue Application error with undefined function csfr_token()

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

working with Laravel and Vue js Application. and I have following welcome.blade.php file script in head tag

```js
<script>
        (function () {
            window.Laravel = {
                csrfToken: '{{ csfr_token() }}'
            };
        })();
    </script>
```

and try to upload image in category.vue file as following

```html
<Modal
                   v-model="addModal"
                   title="Add Category"
                   :mask-closable="false"
                   :closable="false"
                   >
                   
                  <Input v-model="data.tagName" placeholder="Add Category Name" style="width: 300px" />
                  <div class="space"></div>
                  <Upload
                    
                     type="drag"
                     :headers="{'x-csrf-token' : token}"
                     action="/app/upload">
                     <div style="padding: 20px 0">
                     <Icon type="ios-cloud-upload" size="52" style="color: #3399ff"></Icon>
                     <p>Click or drag files here to upload</p>
                      </div>
                    </Upload>
                  <div slot="footer">
                      <Button type="default" @click="addModal">Close</Button>
                      <Button type="primary" @click="addTag" :disabled="isAdding" :loading="isAdding">{{isAdding ? 'Adding..' : 'Add Tag'}}</Button>

                  </div>
               </Modal>
```

but when run the program it is generating following error message
`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError Call to undefined function csfr_token() (View: F:\2021 Technics\vue + laravel\fullstack\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)`

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Possibly it should be `csrf_token()`?

Comment: @msbit gotta love spell check

Comment: @msbit yes thanks it is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling mistake. Currect function name is [`csrf_token()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf)

```
<script>
        (function () {
            window.Laravel = {
                csrfToken: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            };
        })();
</script>
```